# After clicking in buttons My App has stopped

Tags: android

```
02-20 13:57:58.601 5952-5952/com.counter.milion.milioncounter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.counter.milion.milioncounter, PID: 5952
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.counter.milion.milioncounter/com.counter.milion.milioncounter.Menu}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2702)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
                                                                                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:435)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2267)
                                                                                    at com.counter.milion.milioncounter.Menu.onCreate(Menu.java:35)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195) 
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:435) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2267) 
                                                                                    at com.counter.milion.milioncounter.Menu.onCreate(Menu.java:35) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195) 
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 35389452 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 32MB until OOM
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:726)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:547)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1014)
                                                                                    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3730)
                                                                                    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3603)
                                                                                    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:762)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3970)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:507)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:199)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:195)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:191)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:435) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2267) 
                                                                                    at com.counter.milion.milioncounter.Menu.onCreate(Menu.java:35) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Comment: where is your code!?

Comment: You need to reformat this so the code is visible without scrolling. Also add an explanation of your intention, what went wrong and your question

Answer (score 1):

are you using **android:onClick="yourfunction"** feature?
If yes check that you declared the right activity in the top of your xml

```
 tools:context="youractivity"
```

Then be sure to have the function implemented in your class:

```
public void yourclick(View v){...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading your stack trace tells me three things:

1. Your activity couldn't load because it couldn't finish inflating the XML layout
2. Your XML layout couldn't finish inflating because it ran out of memory when trying to create a Bitmap

And finally, your answer:

3. Your XML layout is trying to load either too many images or images that are too big for the memory allocated to your application.

You can remedy this in lots of ways, but most simply:

- Reduce the size of your images. (Normally this means resolution.)
- Ensure you're only keeping the images you need in memory. (You might be loading images that are off the screen.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks you very much if you want send me your email i have a other question